# Drips in my DIY bathtub reglaze

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, refinishing, glazing

I used the Bathworks re-glaze kit on my bathtub. 
 I did amazing prep but then I used too much paint.

The entire thing started to slide and then I got drips that I was unable to get rid of.  Now that it is dried I'm wondering if I can gently sand out the drips with fine grit.

I have read that I could sand and then follow by using a polisher with a rubbing compound.

Has anyone done this?  Tips welcome.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Have you read the instructions, visited the manufacturers web site and/or contacted them via phone or email? They would be the authoritative source on their product... While you're waiting on a response (from them or from us) feel free to take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you'll know how to get the best from this site.

Comment: I have polished out a drip or two using very fine paper wet and buffed out finishes but a slip or slide I’d a big area and may be tough but it’s worth a try I use 1200 grit to start but a big area or larger may require 600 or 400 to start then go finer and finish buff.

Comment: Yes, use (wet) sandpaper with a rigid sanding block to knock down the proud drip, then polish out the result with compound.